# Why Is the Display of a Raster in ARCGIS so Slow?

Tags: performance, gis

I would like to improve the time it takes to display raster data to the screen in ArcGIS. I work with a lot of DEM's and Lidar data and sometimes I will wait for 3 to 5 minutes just to display this data to the screen. And another 3 to 5 minutes every time I pan or zoom.  No processing is involved. I am just basically displaying a raster. I am trying to find out why it is taking so long.

I have looked in Task Manager and my CPU utilization is only around 2.5%, my GPU usage is only around 3%, my hard disk is peaking at 1 MB/s. All data is on the local machine, so no network access is involved.

The system hardware don't seem to be getting utilized very much.  What is causing the display to be so slow?  Given the apparent hardware utilization, I don't know what I can do to speed things up.  I am getting ready to evaluate some VERY large datasets and i would like to not have to wait 10 minutes every time I display one to the screen.  Any processing will take time, I understand that, but I would like to be able to at least see the data in my lifetime.  My gut says that a faster graphics card might help, but my present GPU utilization is only 3%, so that does not seem to be the right direction.

My system consists of: 2-12 core Xeon 6146 CPU's 3.2GHz,
256 Gig of RAM,
an Nvidia 2080 Ti Graphics Card,
a 1.2TB Intel 905 PCIe Boot Drive,
an 8TB RAID 0 consisting of 4 Samsung 980 M.2 disks on a Highpoint controller card.

Why is it taking me 4 minutes to display a static raster to the screen, and what can I do to speed this up?  The Very large data sets that I will soon need to start evaluating are going to kill me.

Comment: I'd probably ask for this to be migrated to https://gis.stackexchange.com/ – we have 20 ArcGIS-related threads, they have 20k of them.